# Connect to MySql database with OpenSSL while on localhost

Tags: mysql, performance, ssl, openssl, scalability

The MySql server and client are on the same server.  In time, they will be on separate machines.  We want to establish secure protocols from the get go.

Does it make sense to require SSL on database connections? Or put another way, is there any reason NOT to use SSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I'd refrain from connecting to `localhost`, and instead connect to your local machine by using its explicit hostname.  I think you're also wise to use TLS / SSL to connect in this configuration if that's what you're expecting to use when you deploy in production.

You may want to ask yourself whether that's worth the trouble, though.  If your app - to - mysqld connection is on a private backend network (as it may be) using TLS / SSL may be overkill. It's called "transport layer security" and it pretty much protects against badguys intercepting data going to and from mysql.  Your app system will probably have other vulnerabilities that render TLS protection uninteresting. For example, if it's a web app the mysql password is probably hardcoded in a config file someplace. If the badguy wants to look at your data, he need only grab the password and log in to the mysqld. To keep your info safe you need to keep badguys off your private network.

It's a good idea always to paramaterize the hostname, port number, and production password of your mysql database. If those things are parameterized you can then deploy to a staging or production server system simply by changing those parameters.